# Are there any sample projects for Flashpunk?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Are there any open source games using Flashpunk? The other big flash game library Flixel has a number of example projects, are there any equivalents for Flashpunk?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2010/03/19/flashpunk-tutorials.aspx. The tutorials are a little old now, but should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this stuff seems seriously out of date. It looks like they have restructured a lot of the library since this has been written.

Answer (score 1):

this could help you:

https://github.com/Gornova/EscapeIn60Seconds

I've doing that for LD21, here the game itself:

http://www.kongregate.com/games/Gornova81/escape-in-60-seconds

Answer (score 1):

For the last [Ludum Dare competition](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-21/?action=top) there were some games that used FlashPunk:

- #1 Flee Buster - Chevy Ray (creator of FlashPunk)
- #7 McPixel - Sos
- #8 Hollow - Connor Ullman
- #27 Reach For It - Noel Berry

Once you start browsing the FlashPunk forums, these names will become familiar. Oh yeah, the forums have [tutorials](http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?board=8.0) too.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably resurrecting a very old topic, but I open-sourced a small platformer game I made for an artist on Flash Game License. The game didn't sell (as I never thought it would) but I made it for the learning experience.

Take a look here:

http://www.github.com/ericmbernier/GemCollector

Be forewarned though, the code is pretty ugly in spots, as I threw it together in a matter of days with no concern for code quality. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open source resources that I've found so far.

- [JRPG Engine](https://github.com/dolgion1/FlashPunk-JRPG-Engine)
- [The Killer](https://github.com/JordanMagnuson/The-Killer)